# Android Studio, Constraint Widget does not work

Tags: android-studio, constraints

In my Android Studio my constraint widget does not work. Whenever I put in a value for the top margin the design doesn't change. for example, in the image you will see 84 in the constraint widget I want to change it to 20 but when I do nothing happens. How do I make this work?

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ALButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onBtnClick"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtxtName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtxtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtVw" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the design image:
[image]

Comment: Same problem here. The value can be set in the widget but it is not propagated. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem here. looks like a bug in your version of Android Studio. Try using Android Studio Arctic Fox|2020.3.1 Patch 2